# How to determine and setup DNS for AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have setup a S3 bucket on AWS. Files need to be sent via SFTP to the S3 bucket and from the bucket files we need to be transfer via SFTP to another server. The SFTP server has been setup in AWS. The IP address of S3 bucket needs to be whitelisted on both sides for receiving and sending files.

The IP address of the S3 bucket keeps changing dynamically. So how to figure out DNS for the s3 bucket and thereby create a CNAME that could be used for whitelisting?

Using elastic IP addresses or Application Load Balancers doesn't seem a feasible solution as they would incur cost and require lot of approvals.

Comment: The Amazon S3 service uses a range of IP addresses as documented in [AWS IP address ranges - Amazon Virtual Private Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/aws-ip-ranges.html). However, I don't know what you mean by "The IP address of S3 bucket needs to be whitelisted" because S3 is not directly communicating with the SFTP server. Can you tell us more about how/where this whitelisting will be applied? Will it be on the Security Groups associated with an Amazon EC2 instance?